# Calculating strengths and weaknesses of an exam taker

Tags: fractions, percentages

I have an exam that users on the site will take. The questions have been divided into four categories:

1. Algebra
2. Fractions
3. Logic
4. Probability.

As of now questions for probability are very few in number. I am trying to decide what are strengths and weaknesses of a user who takes the exam. I know that:
$\frac{\text{specific category answered correctly}}{\text{number of category questions answered}}$ would be a possible solution. But I feel that this would be skewed in terms of categories like probability where the question numbers are few so getting one right would marginally increase the ratio. My question is there a better way to calculate this rather than just simple ratios.

Comment: Getting one right in small categories increases the ratio greatly, not marginally.  The basic answer is to make more probability questions.  You have a smaller sample, so less accuracy in the sample.  You could also rate users competitively because the algebra questions may be systematically easier than the fractions questions, so everybody gets most of them right.

Comment: @RossMillikan is there any other way to compromise for the limited number of probability questions. Especially since I am unable to add more probability questions.

Comment: For each category, you calculate the ratio of number of correct answers to number of  questions *asked* in that category. Then divide that ratio by the average ratio of all answerers in that category. Once you've built up a large sample, you will have a number that most closely reflects how well the person did in that category. Differences between categories, such as number of questions and relative hardness of the problems chosen are automatically adjusted for.